# Table with different border style?

Tags: tables, border

I need to create table like this:

[image: table with different borders]

Is it possible, and if it is, how?

Thank you

Comment: have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With use of `booktabs` and `tabular` package (needed only one compilation for final result):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{LcL}
        \toprule[2pt]
        \midrule
\textbf{Some text}  && \textbf{Some text}   \\
Another text        && Another text         \\
    \cmidrule{1-1}  \cmidrule{3-3}
\textbf{Some text}  && \textbf{Some text}   \\
Another text        && Another text         \\
    \cmidrule{1-1}  \cmidrule{3-3}
\textbf{Some text}  && \textbf{Some text}   \\
Another text        && Another text         \\
        \midrule
        \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{LcL}
        \toprule[2pt]
        \midrule
\textbf{Some text}  && \textbf{Some text}   \\
Another text        && Another text         \\
    \cmidrule{1-1}  \cmidrule{3-3}
\textbf{Some text}  && \textbf{Some text}   \\
Another text        && \lipsum[66]          \\
    \cmidrule{1-1}  \cmidrule{3-3}
\textbf{Some text}  && \textbf{Some text}   \\
Another text        && Another text         \\
        \midrule
        \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep- 
 1.5\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep- 
 1.5\arrayrulewidth}}


\begin{document}
    
    \noindent
    \begin{NiceTabular}{P{0.4}Y{.1}P{0.4}}[]
        \toprule[2pt]
        \toprule 
        \textbf{Level 1} && \textbf{Level 2}\\ 
    blah blah blah && long long line\\\cmidrule{1-1}  \cmidrule{3-3}
            \textbf{Level 1} && \textbf{Level 2}\\ 
    blah blah blah && long long line\\\cmidrule{1-1}  \cmidrule{3-3}
            \textbf{Level 1} && \textbf{Level 2}\\ 
    blah blah blah && long long line\\
        \bottomrule
        \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```